# Pause the folium timestampedgeojson plugin using a PyQt button

Tags: python, plugins, pyqt5, folium

We can play the *timestampedgeojson* plugin over the folium map using a PyQt button but how can we pause the folium *timestampedgeojson* plugin using a PyQt button in PyQt GUI and without using the plugin slider on the map?

As you can see, the plugin slider in the below image. I want to pause it with another PyQt button.

How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please share a sample script, so we can test it and provide you with a solution? Otherwise, no one probably would bother to write code from scratch.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, updated.

Comment: The question is about how to pause the plugin. Can you please throw some light on the button logic.